# Vuetify v-switch not toggling visually

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using v-swich component in one of my child components.
The component itself is rendered at view but when i click on it the toogle doesn't
change the state visually.

I followed this Tutorial to import v-switch manually into child component
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/a-la-carte/#manually-importing

Child Component

```
<template>
    <v-switch v-model="switch1" :label="`Switch 1: ${switch1.toString()}`"></v-switch>
</template>


<script>
import { VSwitch } from 'vuetify/lib'

export default {
    name: 'Configurator',
    components: {
        VSwitch
    },
    props: ['product', 'variants'],
    data()
    {
        return {
            switch1: true
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import ConfiguratorApp from './components/Configurator.App';

let vm = new Vue({
    el: '#configurator-app',
    render: h => h(ConfiguratorApp)
});
```

So what i'm missing here?

Comment: Did you add <v-app> on one of your parent component's template?
If you didn't, you need to add it as a top element.
For example, <v-app><v-switch ... ></v-switch><v-app>

Comment: @endmaster0809: thanks, the v-app was missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vuetify needs its wrapper `v-app` in order to function properly.

```xml
<template>
  <v-app>
      <v-switch v-model="switch1" :label="`Switch 1: ${switch1.toString()}`"></v-switch>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Just add that as your app's root component.